# Programmatic Joda Time formatter

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to create a Joda 2.2 `DateTimeFormatter` to refactor my code. The behaviour that I am trying to reproduce is

```
private String getSemesterLabel() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(date.toString("yyyy"));
    if (date.getMonthOfYear() < 7) {
        sb.insert(0, "first semester ");
    } else {
        sb.insert(0, "second semester ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

What is the simplest way to obtain a `DateTimeFormatter` that would encapsulate the above behaviour ?

Comment: I find your comment and down-vote rather rash, as I have read the whole documentation but couldn't find anything relevant. The only way I have found as of yet is to create a whole DateTimeFormatter from scratch, which is way too much to be worth the refactoring.
Because I don't have a clue how to do something (which explains that I don't see any details I could provide) doesn't mean the question is not legitimate.

Comment: I think I completely misunderstood your question. Are you hoping to find a single formatter that understands the concept of semesters?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "single". I am trying to create a `DateTimeFormatter` object that would encapsulate the business behaviour described in the above code. I do not think the answer is as simple as a `DateTimeFormat#forPattern(String)`.

If you down-voted by mistake. I would appreciate you up-voting back. Thank you.

Comment: Understood. I think my answer now defines the two ways you could approach this. I've removed my down-vote, since your additional comments have now explained your context in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot print semester information using the built-in pattern symbols (see this [similar issue in a bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/joda-time/discussion/337835/thread/79259c3c/)). You have two options:

1. **Build the logic from scratch**

   You can produce `DateTimeFormatter` instances using static methods from the `DateTimeFormat` class:

   ```
   DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy");
   ```

   You can also retrieve the month of the year from a Joda `DateTime` by calling:

   ```
   myDateTime.monthOfYear().get();
   ```
2. **Use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to construct a formatter**

   An alternative, might be to use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to construct a custom `DateTimeFormatter` that displays your preferred text. Something like:

   ```
   DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
   builder.append(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy"));
   builder.appendLiteral(' ');
   builder.append(new SemesterPrinter());
   return builder.toFormatter();
   ```

   where `SemesterPrinter` would need to implement [`DateTimePrinter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimePrinter.html) and would be reponsible for producing the text `first semester` or `second semester` based on the supplied date information..

Comment: Well, I can not see how this will print "first semester" or "second semester"... Printing only the year is the (very) easy part...

Comment: @LudovicPénet Ah, on second thought I may have misunderstood the question. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I feared that I would indeed have to construct the DateTimePrinter from scratch...